# Что такое AssertionError? В каком случае я должен его возбуждать в собственном коде?

Tags: java, исключения, assertion

В пункте 2 книги "Effective Java, 2nd edition" есть этот фрагмент кода, в котором автор хочет запретить пустую инициализацию объекта.

```
class Example {
    private Example() {
        throw new AssertionError();
    }
}
```

Меня сбивает с толку тип возбуждаемого исключения.

Я не понимаю, почему возбуждается `AssertionError`. То ли из-за отсутствия более подходящего типа исключения, то ли потому, что так просто должно быть.

Насколько я понимаю, это исключение возбуждается, когда не проходит проверка `assert`. Также в javadoc просто написано

> [An AssertionError is] Thrown to indicate that an assertion has failed.

Но я не вижу, чтобы здесь выполнялся какой-либо assert (проверка истинного-ложного утверждения).
Конечно, утверждение "Вы не должны создавать экземпляр элемента этого класса" было нарушено, но если следовать этой логике, то мы все должны возбуждать `AssertionError` повсеместно, а это явно не то, что мы делаем.

Чего бы это не стоило, я бы возбудил

```
new IllegalStateException("Must not instantiate an element of this class")
```

Что с этим не так? В каких случаях я должен возбуждать `AssertionError` в собственном коде?

Извините, просто у меня есть небольшое сомнение, потому что я очень часто использую этот паттерн в собственном коде и я хочу быть уверенным, что я всё делаю правильно.

---

<sub>Перевод [вопроса участника doplumi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24863185/10941639).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24863185/10941639

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смысл `AssertionError` состоит в том, что произошло то, что разработчик считал невозможным.

Таким образом, если когда-либо возникает `AssertionError`, это явный признак ошибки программирования

---

<sub>Перевод [ответа участника Henry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24863229/10941639).</sub>